# Extract Last Number from Filename in Bash

Tags: string, bash

I have a lot of files to rename. Nearly all of those files are pictures.

The Source Filenames are something like:

```
DSC08828.JPG       => 08828.JPG
20130412_0001.JPG  => 0001.JPG
0002.JPG           => 0002.JPG
IMG0047.jpg        => 0047.jpg
DSC08828_1.JPG     => Is a duplicate should be ignored
...
DSC08828_9.JPG     => Is a duplicate should be ignored
```

All I want to do is to get the last Number followed by the file extension in a way that is as fast as possible (as we are talking about nearly 600.000 Pictures)

So I want to get the String from the first occurence of at least two digits from the right after the dot until the first non number character. If there is only one digit from the right, the file should be ignored.

Comment: Thanks. That was fast! All of your solutions give quite good results when adapted to my script. I love this community.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a method using a `sed` which may improve performance:

```
ls *.{JPG,jpg} | \
sed '
    /_[1-9]*\./d;    # first drop any line that appears to be a duplicate   
    /^[0-9]*\./d;    # drop any line that does not need to be renamed   
    s/\(.*\)/\1 \1/; # save the original filename by duplicating the pattern space
    s/ .*_/ /;       # remove any leading characters followed by and including _ in the new filename
    s/ [A-Z]*/ /;    # remove any leading capital letters from the new filename
    s/^/mv -i /;     # finally insert mv command at the beginning of the line
'
```

When you're satisfied with the commands, feed to `sh`.

**Input:**

```
0002.JPG
20130412_0001.JPG
DSC08828.JPG
DSC08828_1.JPG
DSC08828_9.JPG
IMG0047.jpg
```

**Output:**

```
mv -i 20130412_0001.JPG 0001.JPG
mv -i DSC08828.JPG 08828.JPG
mv -i IMG0047.jpg 0047.jpg
```

Comment: This is surely going to fail with 600000 files, as you'll exceed the maximum length of command line: on my machine, `getconf ARG_MAX` outputs `2097152` and the files have at least 5 characters so with 600000 files, that's already exceeded. Moreover, [don't parse the output of `ls`](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs). Especially, here, you _really_ don't need `ls`! look at your command `ls *.{JPG,jpg}`: first the shell sees the brace and expands it; it's left with `ls *.JPG *.jpg`; it then performs the pathname expansion and tries to feed that to `ls`! it's useless!

Comment: What will `ls` do with that anyway? it will sort the arguments and outputs them. You might as well just do: `printf '%s\n' *.{JPG,jpg}`. Now, globs are slow in shells, so a method using `find` would be more appropriate.

Comment: the base question about how to get the new name for the file is answered. I iterate over the files in Folders (one folder per day) Structure: 2013/12/31/BildXXXX.jpg and place them in a new structure with new names.

Comment: @gniourf_gniourf I expect most shells will read commands line by line from stdin. Are you suggesting that bash would slurp all command lines before executing them?

Comment: What do you mean by _slurp all command lines_? my point is that it's the shell that expands the wildcards `*.JPG` and `*.jpg` and then passes these as arguments to `ls`. So `ls` would see the 600000 arguments... I'm not talking about feeding the output of `sed` to `sh`, this part is fine.

Comment: @gniourf_gniourf I see. I misunderstood your comment.

Answer (score 1):

```
for x in ./*.JPG ./*.jpg; do
    y=$(echo "$x"|sed '/[^0-9]//g');
    echo "$x" "$y";
done
```

While I'm not giving you the final answer on the plate, this should get you started and illustrate the technique how to approach the tasks you described.

Depending on what you want to do with the files afterwards, you could also combine `find` and `grep`, such as `find . -type f | grep -v '_[0-9]\.'` to filter all files containing `_` followed by one digit, followed by one dot (not tested, escaping might be necessary). `-v` is used to negate the matches filtered by `grep`.

Since in your post you told you want to rename filter AND provided an example where you filter some files, I'm guessing you'll need both: first, filter the files you don't want, and then rename the filtered ones in a `for` loop.

Answer (score 1):

```
sed -nr 's%^.*[^0-9]([0-9]{2,}\.[^.]+)$%\1%p' < <(find ./ -type f -iname '*.JPG')
```

SED dramatically faster than BASH in regexp processing, so use it instead of =~ whenever possible.